# Process Builder : Problem with update related records action

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, update

I have a Process on `User Object` that fires when a user is deactivated.

One of actions i have is to update those accounts that have `OwnerId` equal to user being deactivated. but it doesn't work.

This is a screen shot of the action that update related Accounts :

[image]

More details:

If the Owner is equal to the user being deactivated I have to change the Account Owner to another user.

[User].Id is the id of the logged-in user, but this is not the problem, because I had this field set to a normal Id (Not a Reference) and it doesn't work.

To verify it didn't work, I checked the `LastModifedDate` for the corresponding Accounts and the value didn't change.

If this Problem can be solved with `Flow` it will be great

Comment: What are you trying to update on accounts that are related to user ?  If you are trying to update user Id, What will be the new user Id be ?

Comment: the Owner of the Account : if the Owner is equal to the user being deactivated i have to change the Account Owner to another user

Comment: The process builder you have would set the owner id to the user.id of the user being deactivated.

Comment: [User].Id  is the id of the logged-in user, but this is not the problem, because i had this field set to a normal Id (Not a Reference) and it doesn't work. Besides i cheched the LastModifedDate for the corresponding Accounts and it didn't change

Comment: this should be done with an invocable action that kicks off a scheduled batch job as there could be thousands of Accounts for a batch of deactivated users (DataLoader use case)